# Ubuntu start up issue

Tags: unity, startup

Very new to Linux.

Did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, formatted all my drives.

Everything is working fine, except on start-up I'm getting an internal error saying:

```
/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy and paste or screenshot the complete error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug that was fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1326636

Open the dash, search for "Software Updater," and let it install updates for you. If that doesn't work, then the problem is somewhere else. Since everything else seems to work, I'd say just wait a few days and see if it sorts itself out. That's what works for me whenever I have a login error.